# Cross compiling, missing packages

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling, raspberry-pi

I'm working on Linux PC x86_64.

I've set up a cross compile toolchain for raspberry pi and I can compile basic helloworld and run it on raspberry.

I'm stuck at compiling some open-source programs as `./configure` is complaining about missing packages, for example:

```
configure: No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

I'm using this. `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf` to cross compile and it looks good until that error above.

Should I tell `./configure` to use libs from target system or? How to do it?

Comment: Consider using a build environment like [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/).  Some packages are already defined, but if you have to add a package, you will have to learn how to script invoking the package's config.

Answer (score -1):

Pass options to the configure script so that it finds the development headers and libraries. It uses using `LDFLAGS` and `CFLAGS`.